# Spark Rdd handle different fields of each row by field name

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to Spark and Scala, now I'm somehow stuck with a problem: how to handle different field of each row by field name, then into a new `rdd`.

This is my pseudo code：

```
val newRdd = df.rdd.map(x=>{
        def Random1 => random(1,10000)  //pseudo
        def Random2 => random(10000,20000)  //pseduo
        x.schema.map(y=> {
          if (y.name == "XXX1")
            x.getAs[y.dataType](y.name)) = Random1
          else if (y.name == "XXX2")
            x.getAs[y.dataType](y.name)) = Random2
          else 
            x.getAs[y.dataType](y.name))  //pseduo,keeper the same
        })
      })
```

There are 2 less errors in above:

1. the second map,"x.getAs" is a error syntax
2. how to into a new `rdd`

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

---

Thanks Ramesh Maharjan, it works now.

```
def randomString(len: Int): String = {
    val rand = new scala.util.Random(System.nanoTime)
    val sb = new StringBuilder(len)
    val ab = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    for (i <- 0 until len) {
      sb.append(ab(rand.nextInt(ab.length)))
    }
    sb.toString
  }
 def testUdf = udf((value: String) =>randomString(2))
 val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(Seq((1,"Android"), (2, "iPhone")))
 df.withColumn("_2", testUdf(df("_2")))
+---+---+
| _1| _2|
+---+---+
|  1| F3|
|  2| Ag|
+---+---+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are intending to filter certain felds "XXX1" "XXX2" then simple `select` function should do the trick

```
df.select("XXX1", "XXX2")
```

and convert that to `rdd`
If you are intending something else then your `x.getAs` should look as below

```
 val random1 = x.getAs(y.name)
```

It seems that you are trying to change values in some columns "XXX1" and "XXX2" 
For that a simple `udf` function and `withColumn` should do the trick
Simple `udf` function is as below

```
  def testUdf = udf((value: String) => {
    //do your logics here and what you return from here would be reflected in the value you passed from the column
  })
```

And you can call the udf function as

```
df.withColumn("XXX1", testUdf(df("XXX1")))
```

Similarly you can do for "XXX2"

Comment: thanks your quick reply, but I want to get a new RDD which change special  odd RDD filed and other fields keep unchanged.

Comment: yes, I also think  "udf". But in my case, every special filed is different.  withColumn would give all the same for a special filed.

Comment: `withColumn` would give the results returned from the `udf function` used. So you can `match cases` for the different fields in the `udf` in order to get different values.

Comment: @Tamesh Maharjan -  sorry for later, it works well, thanks a lot.

Comment: My pleasure @meng . By the way you got my name wrong. :) An upvote should help me too if the answer is useful to you :)

Comment: Sure, it's useful. again sorry for my typo, it seems I can't correct your right name in above comment :(, and i just correct in question test：）

Comment: Thank you @meng :)